# Box API change notifications

Tags: box-api

We found recently that our Box application stopped working.
Now I see there's a paper on the web site that states that V1 API got deprecated (https://cloud.app.box.com/s/uoc5cp3vkz6vr95mpsva). Is there a way to subscribe to this sort of notifications? We didn't receive any direct communication nor maillist posted message about this change.

Answer (score 0):

Box emailed every developer that registered as the owner or a developer of an application.  Unfortunately, it sounds like our emails got dropped into your spam box.

You can subscribe to the [RSS feed](http://developers.blog.box.com/feed/) for our developer's Blog, where we tend to announce and link to things like the article you noticed.

There was a steady set of articles in 2013 about the impending deprecation of the old Box API, such as this [one](http://developers.blog.box.com/2013/10/01/start-migrating-to-v2-of-the-content-api-deprecating-v1-in-december/).

Comment: We have 5 developers associated with our applicaion and it looks like neither of them received anything. Could you advise when that email notification took place? We also don't monitor developer blog too often as the application just worked well and didn't require any further development. So I just wonder if you could "shout louder" and directly to developers when you decommissioning services.